# Cleaning up captcha image (reflected text)

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, ocr, captcha

I'm struggling with a captcha image that has reflected letters on the bottom. Taking the shadow off the captcha, it can easily be resolved. I have tried using OpenCV, but no success so far. For example, if the captcha text is "h8mb", it will have a reflected shadow with the "h8mb" text cropped as shown below:

I will link the images below, since I can't add them due to the fact that my account is new.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7vG4.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGufm.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3GWB.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q7hu.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXAWw.jpg

Could someone explain to me how this could be done? Or how could I use OpenCV to do this reflection removal?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, the design of this captcha is pretty poor.

Every sample is made of the word struck out, forming a single, largest blob. The other pieces make distinct and smaller blobs, which are too easy to erase by seed filling.